# Alternative expression for "in association with"

Tags: phrase-requests, phraseology

We're hosting an event soon.

The event is hosted by x, in association with Y.

For visual or presenting purposes I wanted to know if there was a "fancier" or more eloquent way of saying "in association with".

Perhaps in some Latin or French expression, similar to the adoption of raison d'être.

The companies are not joining, allied, in conjunction, or connected.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: If the companies are not joined, allied etc. then a simple statement could be "The event is hosted by X and Y" because an attempt to link them might suggest otherwise.

Comment: 'The event is co-hosted by X and y.'

Comment: What does "in association with" mean? If an event is sponsored by X and/or Y there may be some agreement about the form of words to be used, which may extend to how other entities are referred to (e.g. X pays to be identified as the sole host with other sponsors relegated to a lesser credit, perhaps explicitly paying an associate-tier sum.) "Co-hosted by X and Y" implies an equal contribution from both; "X in association with Y" implies a lesser contribution from Y. But this is far away from English language and usage.